# Spring Boot: Can't get Thymeleaf select box selected option value in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, select, thymeleaf

I know this sounds like a duplicated question, but believe me, I've searched and tried enough but didn't work. So, please help.

I'm trying to load data from the database on change of select box.

My idea is to get the currently selected value of the select box and pass it to the controller. But the problem is I can't get the value.

My select box is rendered in `localhost:9090/admin/orders` with the following code.

```html
<form th:action="@{/status}" method="POST">
    <select name="orderStatus" class="custom-select w-auto">
        <option th:value="1" th:text="Pending"></option>
        <option th:value="2" th:text="Shipping"></option>
        <option th:value="3" th:text="Shipped"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In my `controller`:

```java
@Controller
public class OrderController {
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/status")
    public String filterOrdersByOrderStatus(@RequestParam String orderStatus) {
        
        System.out.println(orderStatus);
        System.out.println("apple");
        
        return "apple";
    }
}
```

On change of select options, I don't get anything in the console.

How can I get that selected value in my controller?

Comment: You just need to submit your form...

Comment: How can I do that? I don't want to have a submit button. @Jakub

Comment: Then you need to play with javascript and ajax request. Thymeleaf is just templaing engine, rendering pages on server side. It's completely invalid tool for your use case. Find out more about how to determine selected option and send async request using javascript.

Comment: Thank you. I've added onchange listener to the select box and when it is changed, I submitted the form.